# Excel tables connected to SQL Server only return numeric columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, odbc

I have created a ODBC connection (ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server) in Excel to access data from a Azure SQL Database and for some reason that I can't understand when I try to query data it returns a table with only the numeric columns populated.

[image: The varchar columns don't have values]

What is strange to me is that those columns are not empty. I can even access it normally using SSMS, Power BI, Dataflows, Azure Data Factory and even Power Query inside Excel. Here it's possible to see the data at SSMS.

[image: populated values]

When query data using SSMS, Power BI Dataflows, Power Query (Excel/Power BI) everything work fine.

The problem seems to be strictly related to the ODBC connection with Excel. All tables return the same error pattern (absence of varchar values). Does anyone has experienced something similar that can help me?

these are part of my ODBC configuration:

```
Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server Version 17.05.0001
Language: (Default)
Data Encryption: Yes
Trust Server Certificate: No
Multiple Active Result Sets(MARS): No
Mirror Server: 
Translate Character Data: Yes
Log Long Running Queries: No
Log Driver Statistics: No
Use Regional Settings: No
Use ANSI Quoted Identifiers: Yes
Use ANSI Null, Paddings and Warnings: Yes
```

And this image contains some information related to one of the tables:
[image: table details]

Comment: It seems that you have "Translate Character Data: Yes" in the ODBC settings, `varchar` columns and the presence of international characters such as c-cedilla and o-tilde. Could there be other Unicode characters in the data that aren't compatible with your collation/code page? Is the problem resolved if you use `nvarchar` columns instead of `varchar`?

Comment: First screenshot appears to be a QueryTable. Please show how you created this object? From code? From Excel ribbon?

Comment: Hello @AlwaysLearning, I did what you suggested and changed to nvarchar and nothing happened. But, I figured out that if I apply a length number to the data type, like NVARCHAR(100) or VARCHAR(100) instead of NVARCHAR(MAX) or VARCHAR(MAX) the query in excel behaves correctly. It's like excel doesn't understand MAX columns.

Comment: Hello @Parfait, the table in the SQL Database was created using the Python Pandas method called df.to_sql(). The table in Excel was created using "Data > Get & Transform Data > Existing Connections > New SQL Server Connection"